# c# string to float convert doesn't work correct

Tags: c#, string, floating-point, converters

I have to convert a string to a float, only the normal converters don't work.

```
fi.Resolution = float.Parse(nodeC.InnerText);
fi.Resolution = (float)nodeC.InnerText; 
fi.Resolution = Single.Parse(nodeC.InnerText);
```

and more of those methods don't work.
When the nodeC.InnerText is 0.01 it returns 1, 
but if nodeC.InnerText is 5.72958e-07 it returns 0,0575958
and 0.0001 also returns 1, so it isn't that it bitshifts.

Does anyone know why this standard c# converts don't work?

So i'm trying to write my own StringToFloat method but it fails :P

```
public float StringToFloat(string input)
        {
            float output = 0;
            char[] arr = input.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i].Equals("."))
                    output += 1;//change
                else
                    output += Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]);
            }

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: What culture are you using?  It looks like `Parse` is treating the decimal as a comma.

Comment: Shouldn't you just do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `fi.Resolution = float.Parse(nodeC.InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

It looks like your current culture is expecting `,` as the decimal separator and ignoring any `.` present.

Hence

```
0.01        =>    001     => 1
5.72958e-07 => 572958e-07 => 0,0572958 (note it gave you a , not a .)
```

Comment: That is some magic, but for me, if I use other separator than specified in my culture I get exception. So I don't think his problem is in culture, but it is first thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance use Windows locale that defaults to "," as the decimal separator?

also:

```
(float)nodeC.InnerText;
```

should never work

Comment: Because `(float)` is attempting to cast from `string` to `float` which is not a valid cast.  You need to parse or convert the string.